# Measured grid in Mapbox

Tags: coordinate-system, mapbox, vector-grid, grids-graticules

I’m trying to create a reference / measured grid in Mapbox so that each grid tile represents a consistent square shape. I know this square shape might not represent a consistent area.

Using long and lat with uniform increments doesn’t appear work currently due to the distortion as you get away from the equator.

[image]

However the outcome required is this:

[image]

After quite a bit of searching I still can’t find any existing approaches to this, I was hoping the community might be able to to help.

---

The current reply does not give desired result as it still gives distortion away from the equator in that perspective and with uniform coordinate lines.

Comment: please stop vandalising the question - please clarify what **exactly** is wrong with the current answer, or clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: The links you provided are about vector tiles, not projections or grids. You seem to be wondering why you're not getting answers yet ignoring questions for clarification in the comments, and the answer from Ian Turton. Also, you haven't provided any information about what you've tried to solve the problem. When you come here asking for help from the community, you are a part of the community. It's a two way street - you have to put in some effort if you want people to put in an effort giving you an answer for free. Your answer is not an answer. Put in some effort and post your actual solution.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You have to offset the coordinates as mapbox doesn’t allow that projection.

Answer (score 8):

If MapBox uses EPSG:3857 any grid will become distorted as you move away from the equator.

If you want an undistorted lat/lon grid try using EPSG:4326 (Plate Carree) - technically the grid is still distorted but it looks OK. (this is what is shown in the 2nd image of your updated question).

If you want a really undistorted then you would be best using a local projection suited to your area of study.

Comment: what3words shows it's grid only at zoom level 19, where grid would have consistent square shape regardless of the projection and location on the map.

Comment: in 4326 the grid squares would **look** square on your map, they would not actually be square (hint: look at a globe)